# API Gateway Simple Bod Mapping Serialization Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have the following body mapping template:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{ 
"TableName": "bars",
 "Item": {
  "barid": "$inputRoot.barid"
}
```

I'm testing an endpoint with this JSON:

```
{
"barid": "002"
}
```

Whenever I try to use this mapping template I get this error:

```
"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"
```

when I try this with input.path('barid') it works fine but when I use inputroot it breaks. Not sure whats happening anything would help. Thanks

Comment: API Gateway doesn't expose SerializationException if there is an issue related to the mapping template. Do you have the raw request to API Gateway?

Comment: This is what I'm putting in the request body when I test it {"barid": "002"}

Comment: Where do you see ""com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"? Can you provide some more details so we can try to reproduce?

Comment: This is an issue with the object being sent to DynamoDB